# Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__column_info' doesn't exist in engine in PhpMyAdmin in XAMPP on MAC

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I upgraded the XAMPP in my Mac 10.11.1 to the latest 5.6.14-4 version.  However, when I add a new database or drop a database, I got an error.

> ### 1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__column_info' doesn't exist in engine

May I know how to fix it?

Comment: I tried XAMPP 5.5.30-4 and also get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The new version xampp-osx-5.6.15-1-installer fixed the problem.